# Inverse problem for MRI imaging

Tags: imaging

Background: Recently, I read a paper describing the existence of what are known as "concomitant gradient fields" in MRI. When a linear gradient is applied along one axis, concomitant gradient fields arise along the orthogonal axes in order to satisfy Maxwell's equations. These gradient fields at lower magnetic field strengths can cause image aberrations.

Problem: How to get estimate the fields? My thought was if you could **use the raw imaging data to map the applied magnetic field in the scanner** than you could determine the concomitant gradient field by subtracting the magnetic field that was supposedly applied from the true magnetic field. The difference should yield the concomitant gradient field. I am having a difficult time determining whether this is possible from the literature.

Comment: I think you might want to read a textbook or two on magnetic resonance. One can map the entire field with sub-ppm precision simply by measuring the resonance frequencies as a function of location, which is done with specifically designed test dummies. A sampling of papers on the topic should also convince you that the reconstruction problems are essentially solved and there is no need to reinvent the wheel at this level.